# Count of elements in a div with certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$('.project-header').html('Projects (' + numProjects + ')');
$('.task-header').html('Tasks (' + numTasks + ')');
$('.case-header').html('Cases (' + numCases + ')');
```

Where numProjects should be for example:

```
$('.project-header').numElementsWith('.external-element');
```

Is there some way to get the number of elements matching the class like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)!

```
var count = $('.project-header').find('.external-element').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.project-header .external-element').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>


$("ul").children().length // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
$('.project-header .external-element').length;
```